# What's the best way to quickly remove unwanted data from a Pandas Dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset formatted like a table (14 columns x 10M rows). Some of the items can be NaNs, which I don't want, and for two columns 'x0' and 'y0', I want to remove values that are outside of -30 to +30.

My code, as shown below, loops through the dataset one row at a time, and it's incredibly slow. Is there a more efficient method of removing the lines I don't want?

```
def cleanDataset(dataset):

    findNanYs = pd.isnull(dataset)
    forDeletion = []

    for i in range(0,dataset.shape[0]):
        if findNanYs.T.any()[i]:  # strike NaN
            forDeletion.append(i)
        elif abs(dataset['x0'][i]) > 30:
            forDeletion.append(i)        
        elif abs(dataset['y0'][i]) > 30:
            forDeletion.append(i)        

    cleanDS = dataset.drop(forDeletion, axis=0)
    return cleanDS
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides *dropna*, given above, use query to filter data, this is much more efficient memory-wise for big tables, as simple as this:

```
dataset.query('-30 < x0 < 30', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

You can find more information about dropna [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

```
This drops NaN rows.
dataset = dataset.dropna(how=any)

# And you can filter and drop unwanted data as below
dataset = dataset.loc[abs(dataset['x0']) > 30]
dataset = dataset.loc[abs(dataset['y0']) > 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
# set number of rows
nrows = 50

# generate dataframe
a = np.random.randn(nrows)
mask = np.random.choice([1, 0], a.shape, p=[.1, .9]).astype(bool)
a[mask] = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': a, 'x0': np.random.randint(-50, 50, nrows), 'y0': np.random.randint(-50, 50, nrows)})

# drop rows
df.x0 = df.x0.where(abs(df.x0) <= 30)
df.y0 = df.y0.where(abs(df.y0) <= 30)
df.dropna()
```